# How to exclude some code of a objective-c package

Tags: ios, swift

I want to exclude some code of an Objective-C package for some build configuration

some code in the package likes

```
#if DEBUG
something 1
#else
something 2
#endif
```

I've tried 2 steps like below but none works:

1. Set `DEBUG=0` in `Preprocessor Macros` in the main project, not works, looks the DEBUG macro in the package is not the same one with the main project
2. Add prefix "**Debug_**" for all files in the package, and set `DEBUG_*` in the 'Excluded Source File Names' of main project

Is there any other way to exclude the files?

Comment: `#if DEBUG` will include the code if `DEBUG` has any value.  0,1,"yes", it doesn't matter. If you don't want to compile that code, don't assign any value to `DEBUG`

Comment: @Paulw11 I include some code in the `DEBUG` in the package because I want to exclude this part in release build, the `DEBUG` macro is `YES` when debugging and `NO` in release mode, but I have some other build configs like SIT UAT but I can't config the value `DEBUG` in the project setting, even I set `DEBUG=1` in the `Preprocessor Macros ` of build setting, the `DEBUG` value in the  package is still 0

Answer (score 0):

Come to post my solution, I define the macro in the Package.swift likes

```
.target(
            name: "Name",
            path: "Path",
            cSettings: [
                .define("MACRO", to: "1", .when(configuration: .debug)),
                .define("MACRO", to: "0", .when(configuration: .release))
            ]
        ),
```

But the bad new is, we only have two options(`.debug` and `.release`) to set, can not add the custom configuration right now :( , hope to support in the future